# SQL Server : distributed transaction and duplicated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, distributed-transactions

I have 1 core SQL Server and many secondary SQL Servers that transfer data to the core server.

Every secondary SQL Server has linked core server and stored procedure that runs from time to time.

This is the code from a stored procedure (some fields are deleted, but it's not improtant)

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION

SELECT TOP (@ReceiptsQuantity) 
    MarketId, CashCheckoutId, ReceiptId, GlobalReceiptId
INTO #Receipts 
FROM dbo.Receipt
WHERE Transmitted = 0

SELECT ReceiptId, Barcode, GoodId
INTO #ReceiptGoodsStrings
FROM ReceiptGoodsStrings
WHERE ReceiptGoodsStrings.ReceiptId in (SELECT ReceiptId FROM #Receipts)

INSERT INTO [SyncServer].[POSServer].[dbo].[Receipt] 
    SELECT * FROM #Receipts

INSERT INTO [SyncServer].[POSServer].[dbo].[ReceiptGoodsStrings] 
    SELECT * FROM #ReceiptGoodsStrings

UPDATE Receipt 
SET Transmitted = 1 
WHERE ReceiptId in (SELECT ReceiptId FROM #Receipts)

DROP TABLE #Receipts 
DROP TABLE #ReceiptGoodsStrings 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

There are s two tables: `Receipts` has many `ReceiptGoodsStrings` (key `ReceiptID`)

It's working fine. But sometimes on core server I have duplicated rows in `Receipts` and `ReceiptGoodsStrings`. It's happening very rarely and I cannot understand why.

Maybe I chose the wrong way to transfer data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is a concurrency problem.

There is a possibility that two concurrent transaction open and both read from your `Receipt` table. Each session is going to write to its own temp tables (`#Receipts` and `#ReceiptGoodsStrings`). At the end, clients intermittently lock `[SyncServer].[POSServer].[dbo].[Receipt]` and `[SyncServer].[POSServer].[dbo].[ReceiptGoodsStrings]` to stuff rows from temp tables to destination and both of them perform an update.

Thus, both transactions are succesfully completed and you have duplicate rows!

Fortunately, you can use UPDLOCK hint on your first select from `Receipt` table to lock the rows/pages you already read while inside a transaction. The other client will have to wait for the lock to be released by the first client performing `COMMIT`. Then, second one will continue, read only new rows to be transmitted and copy them and only them.

```
SELECT TOP (@ReceiptsQuantity) 
    MarketId, CashCheckoutId, ReceiptId, GlobalReceiptId
INTO #Receipts 
FROM dbo.Receipt WITH (UPDLOCK)
WHERE Transmitted = 0
```

**EDIT**

At the end, pay attention to the interval you use to call the sync transaction. It may be that the interval is too short, so the transaction is not yet finished while the new one is starting. In this case you can expect to get the duplicated rows because. You could try to increase the interval.